# Как связать таблицы в  GRIDView?

Tags: yii2, gridview, php

Задача связать 2 таблицы.

Таблица юзеров и коментарии, нужно, чтобы выводило не айди пользователя, а имя его

```
GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            'id',
            'content:ntext',
            'page_id',
            'created',
            'user_id' =>
            [
                'attribute' =>  'user_id',
                **'value' => 'user_id'**,
    //пытался сделать так 'value'=> app\modules\admin\controllers\CommentController::getID('user_id')
            ],
            // 'guest', \app\models\Users::getUsers(user_id)

           ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]);
```

По ключу должен был выбирать юзера, но нифига, говорит, не знает метод `app\modules\admin\controllers\CommentController::getID('user_id')`.

Answer (score 3):

Вариант с минимумом дополнительного кода и максимумом использования возможностей *Yii2*.

Прежде всего, необходимы явно прописанные отношения между моделями *Comment* и *User* (все-таки правильнее будет использовать единственное число при назывании моделей). *Yii2* сам добавляет нужные методы в модели [при генерации кода с помощью *Gii*](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-gii.html), поэтому должны быть такие методы:

```
// app\models\Comment
public function getUser()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'id_user']);
}

// app\models\User
public function getComments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::className(), ['id_user' => 'id']);
}
```

Если их нет, можно добавить вручную. Эти два метода позволят сделать связку моделей в классе *CommentSearch*, заготовка которого опять же сгенерирована *Gii*. В методе *search()* меняем:

```
// app\models\CommentSearch
$query = Comment::find();
```

на:

```
// app\models\CommentSearch
$query = Comment::find()->with('user');
```

Передаем данные из модели в контроллер (в дефолтном контроллере даже менять ничего не нужно):

```
// app\controllers\CommentsController
public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new CommentSearch();
    $dataProvider' = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

И выводим данные с помощью GridView:

```
GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        //...
        'user.name',
        //...
       ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]);
```

Answer (score -2):

Подобную проблему решил созданием представления для обоих таблиц в mysql и последующим созданием модели к этому представлению.